# ¿Porque las variables se quedan estáticas cuando están siendo modificadas en cada bucle?

Tags: java, bucle-for

Al ejecutar el código de queda en un bucle infinito, de tal manera que el valor pi y error se quedan estáticos, ¿esto porque ocurre?

> 312
> 3.0
> 0.14159265358979312
> 3.0
> 0.14159265358979312
> 3.0
> 0.14159265358979312
> 3.0
> 0.14159265358979312
> 3.0
> 0.14159265358979312
> 3.0
> 0.14159265358979312
> 3.0
> 0.14159265358979312
> 3.0

```
       double error = 0;
       double pi = 0;
       double epsilon = 0.5;
       for(int i = 0; error<epsilon; i++) {
           
               pi = pi + Math.pow(-1, i)*(4/((2*i)+1));
               error = Math.PI-Math.abs(pi);
               System.out.println(pi);
               System.out.println(error);
           }
       }
       System.out.println(pi);
       System.out.println(error);
       if(0 <= epsilon && epsilon < 1) {
           pi = pi + Math.pow(-1, i)*(4/((2*i)+1));
           error = Math.PI-Math.abs(pi);
           System.out.println(pi);
           System.out.println(error);
       } else {
           System.out.println("El valor de epsilon introducido debe ser igual o mayor que 0, y menor que 1.");
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Con respecto a tu bucle infinito, esto ocurre ya que en el `for` estas controlando la salida del mismo con las variables:

> `error` = -0.8584 (primer ciclo), 0.1415 (resto de ciclos)
>
> `epsilon` = 0.5 (en todos los ciclos, debido a que no se
> altera)

Como se ve, el valor de `error` nunca va a ser mayor que el valor de `epsilon` por lo tanto quedas en un bucle infinito.

Y por otra parte las variables `pi` y `error` se quedan estaticas porque las operaciones matematicas que estas haciendo retornan ese resultado.